# Cannot Access Empty Property in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting the following error with the following code when attempting to create an instance in another file. I am new to PHP, and can't find any syntax errors with my code.

**Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/leondash/public_html/poll/classes/database.php on line 21**

```
class Database {

    private $host, $username, $password, $database;
    private $db;

    /** Opens a connection the database */
    public function __construct() {
            $this->host     = "localhost";
            $this->username = "dbuser";
            $this->password = "dbpass";
            $this->database = "dbname";

            // the following line is giving the error
            $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->$password, $this->database)
            or die('Error: Could not connect to the database');

            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning to connect to the table "" on host "" with "" as a username and "" as a password?

Comment: See your edit. Can you make the info match your actual info more closely? Just change the host/username/password whatever. having them in the Q as blank doesn't accurately represent your situation considering having them blank sounds like what is causing the error.

Comment: Updated my post, JAL.

Comment: Thanks! I think Darragh probably found it anyhow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You appear to have an error on line 21. Change:

```
$this->$password
```

to:

```
$this->password
```

For reference, this is is known as a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Example:

```php
$a = 'b';
$b = 'I am a variable variable';
echo $$a; // equivalent to `echo $b;` prints 'I am a variable variable'
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to have slipped past my sight.

Comment: Argh, I've upvoted this answer in the past when it pointed out the obvious mistake I made, I just did the same thing again... I wish I could up vote again

Comment: Haha :D No problem! We've all done it - I've certainly done it more than once!

Comment: Hands up, just happened to me - thank you @Darragh !!

Answer (score 1):

They are all empty.

```
        $this->host     = "";
        $this->username = "";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->database = "";
```

You can't the url called "". You can't have username "". You can't have database "". but can have the password "". Thought not recommended.

Comment: Sorry, updated my original post.  The code which is giving me this error does not have those as empty.