# 'cannot access empty property' error in php

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, php-5.5

I am confused where i made mistake in my php code below. Although, i looked numerous time on my code but couldn't find why i am getting this error **'cannot access empty property'** .

```
class DBTest{
//declare variables
private $servername = "localhost";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
private $database = "avn_test";
private static $conn;
private $results;

//constructor
public function __construct(){
self::$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();}
} //close constructor

public function executeQuery($query='') {
if(!empty($query)){
$query = self::$conn->real_escape_string($query);
```

**Error on this line:**

> $this->results = self::$conn->query($query) or die("Error in database
>   connection".self::$conn->$error);

```
if( $this->results->num_rows > 0 ) {
$rowqry = array();
while($row = $this->results->fetch_object()) {
$rowqry[]= $row; } //close of while
$rarray['returnvar'] = $rowqry;
return $rarray;
} else {
return false; } // close of else
}//close of top if
else
return false;
} //close of function

function __destruct(){
self::$conn->close();}
} //close of class

//create an object of class DBTest
$test = new DBTest();
$q= "select * from test";
$tmp = $test->executeQuery($q);

if($tmp){
foreach($tmp as $key => $value){
echo $value;}
}
else
echo 'tmp var is empty';
```

Comment: Please point out your error line with some arrow or like that

Comment: Please show error and dark or comment on that line where it will occur

Comment: and he doesn't need this line anyway since the connection is going to be closed automatically. Also `real_escape_string($query)`?? Not only this function is deprecated, but it's completely the wrong way to use it.

Comment: Use `self::conn` instead of `self::$conn`.

Comment: $conn is static dear. So, how can i use only self::conn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property)

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
$this->results = self::$conn->query($query) or die("Error in database connection".self::$conn->$error);
```

Replace `self::$conn->$error` with `self::$conn->error`.

The `$` is required when accessing a static property, but not needed for instance properties.

Answer (score 0):

No need of `$` in `$conn` function

```
self::$conn replace with self::conn
                           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I didn't checked, but why would it not be needed in `__destruct` but needed elsewhere?