# PHP class, getting outside db connection

Tags: php, class

I have never looked into classes at all so I'm just learning right now.

But like always I got troubles before I've even started -.-

```
class news { 
    public $countNews; 
    public $db;

    public function __construct() { 
        global $_database;
        $this->$db = $_database; 
    }
    public function countNews() { 
        return $this->$db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."news ORDER BY date DESC")->num_rows; 
    }
}
```

This is my code right now, on this example im trying to count news. but it doesn't go to well if i say it like that.

My error right now is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in news.class.php on line 11

Anyone that knows what I'm doing wrong and maybe can point me in the right direction?

Comment: remove the `$`-sign - it is just `$this->db...`

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property/14920231

Comment: Thanks so much @Philipp you really saved me there :D