# PHP Fatal Error: Cannot access empty property

Tags: php, fatal-error

PS: this [previous_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property?rq=1) is not related and does not help..

I am using the FPDF Library, and I am trying to implement the Header() method. I added 2 protected variables to the class and modified the constructor to accept values that will set them. However when I try to access those variables from the Header() method I get ' Fatal error: Cannot access empty property".
I Don't know I am doing wrong. It is driving me crazy.

All I do in my code is:

```
$pdf = new FPDF("Hello", "Whatever");
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage() //this method calls the Header() method , and it get called many times through the code
```

The FPDF class is as follow:

**Full code :** [fpdf library](http://www.fpdf.org/) (do to downloads and get V1.81)

**Header method:** (the foregoing property is $headerLeft)

```
function Header()
{
    $this->Cell(30,10, $this->$headerLeft);

    $this->Ln();
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title

    $this->Cell(30,10,  $this->$headerRight);
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}
```

**fields and constructor:**

```
class FPDF
{
protected $page;               // current page number
protected $n;                  // current object number
protected $offsets;            // array of object offsets
protected $buffer;             // buffer holding in-memory PDF
protected $pages;              // array containing pages
protected $state;              // current document state
protected $compress;           // compression flag
protected $k;                  // scale factor (number of points in user unit)
protected $DefOrientation;     // default orientation
protected $CurOrientation;     // current orientation
protected $StdPageSizes;       // standard page sizes
protected $DefPageSize;        // default page size
protected $CurPageSize;        // current page size
protected $CurRotation;        // current page rotation
protected $PageInfo;           // page-related data
protected $wPt, $hPt;          // dimensions of current page in points
protected $w, $h;              // dimensions of current page in user unit
protected $lMargin;            // left margin
protected $tMargin;            // top margin
protected $rMargin;            // right margin
protected $bMargin;            // page break margin
protected $cMargin;            // cell margin
protected $x, $y;              // current position in user unit
protected $lasth;              // height of last printed cell
protected $LineWidth;          // line width in user unit
protected $fontpath;           // path containing fonts
protected $CoreFonts;          // array of core font names
protected $fonts;              // array of used fonts
protected $FontFiles;          // array of font files
protected $encodings;          // array of encodings
protected $cmaps;              // array of ToUnicode CMaps
protected $FontFamily;         // current font family
protected $FontStyle;          // current font style
protected $underline;          // underlining flag
protected $CurrentFont;        // current font info
protected $FontSizePt;         // current font size in points
protected $FontSize;           // current font size in user unit
protected $DrawColor;          // commands for drawing color
protected $FillColor;          // commands for filling color
protected $TextColor;          // commands for text color
protected $ColorFlag;          // indicates whether fill and text colors are different
protected $WithAlpha;          // indicates whether alpha channel is used
protected $ws;                 // word spacing
protected $images;             // array of used images
protected $PageLinks;          // array of links in pages
protected $links;              // array of internal links
protected $AutoPageBreak;      // automatic page breaking
protected $PageBreakTrigger;   // threshold used to trigger page breaks
protected $InHeader;           // flag set when processing header
protected $InFooter;           // flag set when processing footer
protected $AliasNbPages;       // alias for total number of pages
protected $ZoomMode;           // zoom display mode
protected $LayoutMode;         // layout display mode
protected $metadata;           // document properties
protected $PDFVersion;         // PDF version number
protected $headerLeft;
protected $headerRight;
/*******************************************************************************
*                               Public methods                                 *
*******************************************************************************/

function __construct($hLeft, $hRight, $orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4')
{
    // Some checks
    $this->_dochecks();
    // Initialization of properties
    $this->headerLeft = $hLeft;
    $this->headerRight = $hRight;
    $this->state = 0;
    $this->page = 0;
    $this->n = 2;
    $this->buffer = '';
    $this->pages = array();
    $this->PageInfo = array();
    $this->fonts = array();
    $this->FontFiles = array();
    $this->encodings = array();
    $this->cmaps = array();
    $this->images = array();
    $this->links = array();
    $this->InHeader = false;
    $this->InFooter = false;
    $this->lasth = 0;
    $this->FontFamily = '';
    $this->FontStyle = '';
    $this->FontSizePt = 12;
    $this->underline = false;
    $this->DrawColor = '0 G';
    $this->FillColor = '0 g';
    $this->TextColor = '0 g';
    $this->ColorFlag = false;
    $this->WithAlpha = false;
    $this->ws = 0;

    // Font path
    if(defined('FPDF_FONTPATH'))
    {
        $this->fontpath = FPDF_FONTPATH;
        if(substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='/' && substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='\\')
            $this->fontpath .= '/';
    }
    elseif(is_dir(dirname(__FILE__).'/font'))
        $this->fontpath = dirname(__FILE__).'/font/';
    else
        $this->fontpath = '';
    // Core fonts
    $this->CoreFonts = array('courier', 'helvetica', 'times', 'symbol', 'zapfdingbats');
    // Scale factor
    if($unit=='pt')
        $this->k = 1;
    elseif($unit=='mm')
        $this->k = 72/25.4;
    elseif($unit=='cm')
        $this->k = 72/2.54;
    elseif($unit=='in')
        $this->k = 72;
    else
        $this->Error('Incorrect unit: '.$unit);
    // Page sizes
    $this->StdPageSizes = array('a3'=>array(841.89,1190.55), 'a4'=>array(595.28,841.89), 'a5'=>array(420.94,595.28),
        'letter'=>array(612,792), 'legal'=>array(612,1008));
    $size = $this->_getpagesize($size);
    $this->DefPageSize = $size;
    $this->CurPageSize = $size;
    // Page orientation
    $orientation = strtolower($orientation);
    if($orientation=='p' || $orientation=='portrait')
    {
        $this->DefOrientation = 'P';
        $this->w = $size[0];
        $this->h = $size[1];
    }
    elseif($orientation=='l' || $orientation=='landscape')
    {
        $this->DefOrientation = 'L';
        $this->w = $size[1];
        $this->h = $size[0];
    }
    else
        $this->Error('Incorrect orientation: '.$orientation);
    $this->CurOrientation = $this->DefOrientation;
    $this->wPt = $this->w*$this->k;
    $this->hPt = $this->h*$this->k;
    // Page rotation
    $this->CurRotation = 0;
    // Page margins (1 cm)
    $margin = 28.35/$this->k;
    $this->SetMargins($margin,$margin);
    // Interior cell margin (1 mm)
    $this->cMargin = $margin/10;
    // Line width (0.2 mm)
    $this->LineWidth = .567/$this->k;
    // Automatic page break
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true,2*$margin);
    // Default display mode
    $this->SetDisplayMode('default');
    // Enable compression
    $this->SetCompression(true);
    // Set default PDF version number
    $this->PDFVersion = '1.3';
}

// the rest of the class.....}
```

Comment: How on earth can you say that that other question is unrelated?  You're making the _exact same mistake_

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Cell(30,10, $this->headerLeft);
```

You don't need to $ to access the headerLeft property

Likewise for the headerRight property. You would access that like this

```
$this->headerRight
this->Cell(30,10, $this->headerRight);
```

Comment: The same goes for the `$this->Cell(30,10,  $this->$headerRight);` a few lines beneath.

Comment: Same problem, remove the $ from headerRight