# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property config.php CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem with a project in CAKEPHP 3 , the project is form productive and I try to run this project in my XAMMP but display this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_proyect\admin\cake\libs\configure.php on line 91
```

But, all the kernel files are the ones with the default framework

Thanks

Comment: Pls provide line #91 from `configure.php`

Comment: <code>foreach ($config as $name => $value) {
   if (strpos($name, '.') === false) {
    **$_this->{$name} = $value; //<-This is my line 91in my projec**
   } else {
    $names = explode('.', $name, 4);
    switch (count($names)) {
     case 2: </code>

Comment: _**$_this->{$name} = $value; //<-This is my line 91in my project**_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property)

Comment: Edit your question to put the code in there, properly formatted

Comment: Thanks , I can fix the problem , is for the php version in the framework , the problem was $_this->*{$name} * because is $_this->name and my php is 5