# PHP / paypal - How to make calls on static functions from methods within a different object?

Tags: php, object, paypal, static-methods

I am implementing a paypal payment within a project.

Following paypals instructions I built a procedural php file to get a users payment. This worked so I took the next step to make it a class.

Within this class I call a static method from a class provided by paypal.
This call gives back an error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in line xy.

By this line:

```php
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
```

the class is made available.

This line throws the error:

```php
/*xy=>*/ $this->payment = Payment::get ( $this->paymentId, $this->apiContext );
```

First I checked that `$this->paymentId` and `$this->apiContext` are populated and not empty.

( `xy=>` is the line number ).

usually I separate variables by lines but the editor here does not support it so do not wonder why I only tried to experiment with paymentID and not with apiContext. This is because apiContext is in the next line (xy+1 ) within my source code.

I tried to transfer the volume of `$this->paymentId` to a variable `$abc` and then tried the call:

```php
$abc = $this->paymentId;
/*xy=>*/ $this->payment = Payment::get ( $abc, $this->apiContext );
```

Then I tried to instantiate the paypal class before calling the funtion like:

```
$ppobj= new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
/*xy=>*/ $this->payment = $ppobj->Payment::get ( $this->paymentId, $this->apiContext );
```

And I tried a call like:

```php
$this->payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get( $this->paymentId, $this->apiContext );
```

Please be so kind and tell me what I am doing wrong and what I am supposed to do.

Comment: _"the class is made available"_  but have you also made sure all its dependencies are available, such as `PayPal\Validation\ArgumentValidator` and `PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel`

Comment: Also, you get that error if you try something like `$this->$paymentId` (notice the extra `$`). See [PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920216/php-fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property). Are you absolutely sure you have nothing like that in your code?

Comment: It also sounds like your error reporting is not high enough and may be missing `E_NOTICE` level errors. See [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)